# php's ini_set('max_execution_time', 0) not working

Tags: php

I am trying to execute a script which will run for more than 20 mins. I tried to increase the maximum execution time of PHP by `ini_set('max_execution_time', 0);` and also `set_time_limit(3600);`  But nothing works. It returns the following error.

**Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 500 (Internal Server Error)**

Comment: Possible Duplicate For https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1590441/ini-set-set-time-limit-max-execution-time-not-working?rq=1

Comment: That's a browser response, look at your server log for the error.

Comment: @AdhershMNair - Isn't PHP silent if `ini_set()` is called and it does nothing? It doesn't cause a fatal error AFAIK.

Comment: Try checking the apache error.log file, you will get more explicit details where the code is failing

Comment: Check your web server configuration, it has it's own timeout configuration. For example nginx: `fastcgi_read_timeout`.