# max_execution_time not working but on echo ini_get('max_execution_time') it shows the time what i provide

Tags: php, php-ini

hi don't know how to get out of this situation i am trying to increase the max_execution_time to 5000 for e.g ini_set('max_execution_time',5000). it do shows the execution_time set to 5000 on echo ini_get('max_execution_time') however it dosen't work as connection with server closes early than 5000 sec.

I am trying to fetch XML with the API and then converting that data in  array and that array afterwards is being used in loop to insert array values in my database. I am using codeignitor please see the below code.

My controller

```
public function get_chassis_badge_detail()
    {
        $this->load->model('md_api_test','md_api');
        if($this->md_api->get_chassis_badge_detail())
        {
            $this->load->view('api_test',['car_detail' => '']);
        }
    }
```

My Model:

```
public function get_chassis_badge_detail()
{
    //// for kuzov insertion in to database from stats auction

    $this->load->library('auction_api');
    $query = "select count(distinct kuzov) from stats";
    $total_kuzov = $this->auction_api->aj_get_clean($query);
    $cycle_end = round($total_kuzov[0]['TAG0']/250)+1;

    $query = "select kuzov,model_id from stats group by kuzov order by model_id ASC";

    $arr = '';
    for($k=0; $k<($cycle_end); $k++)
    {
        $query .= " limit ".($k*250).",250";
        $arr[] = $this->auction_api->aj_get_clean($query);
        $query = "select kuzov,model_id from stats group by kuzov order by model_id ASC";

        if (isset($arr[$k][0]))
        {
            for($b=0; $b<count($arr[$k]); $b++)
            {
                $trim_val=trim($arr[$k][$b]['KUZOV']);
                if(!empty($trim_val))
                {
                    $this->db->query("INSERT INTO `dd_chassis_badge`(`model_id`, `badge`) VALUES ('".$this->db->escape_str($arr[$k][$b]['MODEL_ID'])."','".$this->db->escape_str($arr[$k][$b]['KUZOV'])."');");
                }
            }
        }
        else
        {
            unset($arr[$k]);
            break;
        }
    }

    return true;
}
```

Comment: Where are you setting the max_execution_time? Is it in the script or within php_ini file?

Comment: You may also need to look at Apache's timeout setting. Apache's timeout value in the httpd.conf file. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9629566/how-to-increase-apache-timeout-directive-in-htaccess

Comment: i am using at the top of my script @bencarter78

Comment: @hamboy75 my script hardly runs for 30 seconds whereas apache default time is 300 sec

Comment: Well if you want to raise the php time to 5000, it is useless if apache timeout is 300 :p, anyways after how much time does it stop?

Comment: 20 seconds @hamboy75

Comment: Another thing, maybe the time problem is not in php/apache, maybe it is a database timeout problem?? :) and you are not allowed to run queries for +20 seconds

Comment: does the database time out really matters if we insert the row even one by one?

Answer (score 0):

Is there a change you're getting an error (and therefore the server is stopping earlier) but not seeing it? Do you have a php.ini file set to show you php errors?

Comment: yes the php.ini file is set to show error. the script seems to work fine till 19 cycle of loop and doesn't throw any error if it is increased than the time outs. the array i am trying to insert in to my database consist of 19000+records.

Comment: Hmmm... take a look at this: https://stackoverflow.com/a/1590644/7399485. Could this be the case?

Comment: FWIW João's link pertains to safe mode, which seems like it was removed in PHP 5.4, so if you're using a later PHP, it may be unlikely that this is your issue. See: http://php.adamharvey.name/manual/en/features.safe-mode.php