# PHP cutting at 30s despite max_execution_time setting

Tags: php

Using `phpinfo()`, I have verified that `PHP` has the following settings:

```
max_execution_time = 120
max_input_time = 120
```

Despite these settings, my `PHP` script is systematically cutting out at 30 seconds (and then `throws a 500 Internal Server Error`). Reviewing the variables displayed when calling `phpinfo()`, I cannot see any variable that is set to 30s.

Is there another `PHP` setting that I can change to extend my `PHP` script execution time?

Comment: Maybe try restarting PHP? Also, try checking this question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1590441/ini-set-set-time-limit-max-execution-time-not-working

Comment: try to change run time by adding this line in your php script `ini_set('max_execution_time', 600); // Set to 10 Min`

Comment: is this running on a shared host? sometimes hosts have software to stop scripts running more than X seconds.

Comment: Also check your webserver's timeout configuration. It may be hardcoded to 30 seconds. See https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/294214