# PHP - ini_set() expects parameter 2 to be string, integer given

Tags: php, types, parameters, version, ini-set

I have this part of code:

```
...
ini_set('max_execution_time', 300);
...
```

Until now it worked. Now i am getting this error:

`ini_set() expects parameter 2 to be string, integer given`

What has changed? Can it be caused by PHP version?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [ini\_set, set\_time\_limit, (max\_execution\_time) - not working](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1590441/ini-set-set-time-limit-max-execution-time-not-working)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

PHP actually expects both parameters of `ini_set()` to be of type `string` and returns a `string`:

> ini_set ( string $varname , string $newvalue ) : string

You can find this in the [PHP manual on `ini_set`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.ini-set.php).

If you have set `strict_types` with

```
declare(strict_types=1);
```

then you will have to change your `ini_set()` values to

```
ini_set('max_execution_time', '300');
```

Comment: So many tutorial out in the wild are teaching us to use **integer** as the seconds parameter, am very surprise to know that the seconds parameter is actually of type **string**...

Answer (score 2):

Not sure how it was working for you. [Here](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.ini-set.php) is the reference. Second parameter needs to be string data type.

Maybe you was using a variable to set it until now and that variable was somehow getting casted to string? not sure.

Anyways, just use string instead of an integer as second parameter:

```
ini_set('max_execution_time', '300');
```

and you should be good.

Weird enough, just now i noticed, giving second parameter as integer is working on my Server.

Also [Here](https://www.php.net/manual/ro/migration70.new-features.php), if you search with "ini_set", the example is given with second parameter as integer:

```
ini_set('assert.exception', 1);
```

It is weird why its not working for you.

Comment: Yes, I already wrapped the value. But still I don't know why it worked until now. The PHP version didn't changed... Still 7.1

Comment: @user3414654 updated the answer, to confirm your initial claim

Answer (score 1):

PHP accept the key value pair in string in PHP [ini_set()](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.ini-set.php).

```
ini_set("max_execution_time", "300");
```

Comment: There already is an answer like this here. Could you explain what is different in your answer?